# Anyone know what programming language this is?

Tags: programming-languages

I have got a forensic case to complete in uni and found this piece of code which it contains a message saying this might be useful in a text file which was in hex. I converted to text and got the following code;

```
#Path to file or directory to change

$path="F:\"

#Earliest and latest times

[DateTime]$min = "6/14/2016" 
[DateTime]$max = "12/1/2016"

$randSeed = new-object random
        Get-ChildItem -Path $path |

ForEach-Object {

    #Get random date
    [DateTime]$date = [Convert]::ToInt64( ($max.ticks * 1.0 - $min.Ticks * 1.0 ) * $randSeed.NextDouble() + $min.Ticks * 1.0 )

    #Assign random date
    $_.CreationTime = $date
    $_.LastAccessTime = $date
    $_.LastWriteTime = $date  
}
```

If anyone knows what programming language and how to run, please state them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search suggests it's probably MS [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell).

There are installation guides for different versions of Windows and even Linux and macOS on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/powershell/powershell#get-powershell).